# How to set an objects rotation to default rotation after applying it to something else

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have a rocket model which i rotated to a certain angle and then (By mistake) applied the rotation,the situation is that i cant undo my actions **:)** so now i cant rotate my rocket back to the default rotation. Please help

Comment: please put some pictures and explain more about the situation

Comment: So wanna know the answer!! :D  I've had this issue too!

Comment: @RBlong2us u meant u have the solution , i actually solved it but that was luck , all the components of the rocket were parented to an empty and i cleared the parent to snap them to original position and rotation , but i would love to know the answere

Comment: I did not know the solution, but I found a youtube Video that looks like it has the answer!  Check it out: https://youtu.be/dP9nFMvH6ms